# Pre-download Windows Update Package on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-server-2012-r2

I am about to maintain a weekly update on a Windows Server. To minimize the down time and the time waiting for the updates to download, is there any way I can pre-download the updates?

There is a setting for Important updates **Download updates but let me choose whether to install them**. It gives me a notification but doesn't really download. I still have to spend an hour on the download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your updates to be downloaded and ready for you to install at a time you choose, you should configure Windows Update to **Download updates but let me choose whether to install them**.

Here's why:

When configured to automatically check for and download updates, Windows Update will search for available updates every 17.6 to 22 hours ([Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc720539%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)).  As soon as new updates are detected they're [downloaded in the background](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968799%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using the Background Intelligent Transfer Service (BITS).

The end result is that when you are ready to install updates, Windows will have already downloaded them for you and all you'll have to do is simply start the installation.

You can confirm updates have been pre-downloaded for you by:

1. Open Windows Update
2. Click the **# important updates are available** hyperlink
3. Select an update
4. Observe in the right pane that the update has finished downloading:
   [image]

*Note: You're probably not noticing that this option is accomplishing your goal because you've not left it configured long enough for Windows to complete its background check for updates*

Comment: Nice, that answer my questions. By the way, if the status is "Update is ready to download", is there any way I can trigger the download manually? It has been there for a day but no download starts.

Comment: @ydoow No, there's nothing you can do short of manually kicking off the installation of the update. Give it time and you'll find that all the updates are ready for you to install each time you're ready to do maintenance.